# how to unit test third-party code in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I'm currently in the process of writing an API for use in a private environment. Some of the functions introduced are promisified versions of third-party functions.

Example:

Third-party code:

```
function someFunction(argument, callback) {
    var command = stuff;
    return this.exec(command, parse_command(callback));
}
```

My code:

```
function promisifiedFunction() {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        third-party.someFunction('argument', function (err, status) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(new Error("FOO"));
            } else {
                return resolve(status.result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

How do I properly unit test these functions?

(note that the third-party code has already been unit tested)

Comment: If you're interacting with components outside of your project, you're probably going to look at creating mocks of the incoming data/responses

Comment: Could you write me an example that shows a conventional way to do that in node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) is tool which will help you to work third party libraries change their functionality and customize functions on you own. It's a big and complex subject, I can't explain in one comment or anwser, but I can give you url of articles which will help you to understand main concepts. This articles helped me when started testing using `sinon.js` hope it will be helpfull to you too.

1) [Official Documentation](http://sinonjs.org/)
(It covers all subjects, but hard to learn from here, not good documentation)

2) [Article 1](http://elijahmanor.com/unit-test-like-a-secret-agent-with-sinon-js/)
(Great article explained with ilustrations)

3) [Article 2](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js)
(From this article everything become clear for me)